# Render a drupal form retrieved by drupal_get_form

Tags: 7, forms

In Drupal 7, I have a preprocess function retrieving a form like so:

```
$contact = drupal_get_form('privatemsg_new');
```

$contact is then a fully populated form array with the right fields and elements. After that, I tried drupal_render and render, but neither one show a themed output in the node. What do I have to do to display the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is to use `drupal_render`, which is used for render arrays like the form is. I tested this with a different form, and got the desired result so what you're doing should be right. Most likely you have a different error some where in your code causing this.

```
$html = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('form_id', $args)));
```

Comment: Doh! I just realized I am in a preprocess function, so it should have been $vars['contact'] with the render. Thanks for helping.

Comment: if use above method, 'form' tag is not rendered

Comment: @Guru If the form tag is not rendered, then you have a different issue. I've done this many times and it have worked fine every time.

Comment: Thanks @googletorp it is working fine. I've also faced another problem. ie, '#ajax' is not triggered when i rendered form by above method. Is any other solutions for this?